# Where can I tell Tomcat where data of a deployed application are to be stored?

Tags: tomcat, h2

I try to deploy an application on Tomcat. The application uses a database. But Tomcat cannot store it, because He tries storing in the root directory of the server, where he has no permission of course, log says:

```
Error opening database: "Could not save properties /sudoDb.lock.db" [8000-176]
```

How can I configure Tomcat to store anywhere, that is permitted, eg. TOMCAT_HOME or anywhere else.

thanks for any hint

Comment: Please provide details about your used frameworks, configuration and source code and at minimum least a full exception StackTrace.

Comment: it is a grails application, where I only can configure url = "jdbc:h2:sudoDb;...." I have deployed the application on another tomcat, where tomcat stores database in TOMCAT_HOME/bin and everything works fine. I repeat my question: Can I tell tomcat, where to store where to store the database. If such a simple question cannot be answered without stacktrace and config Information I must suppose database storing by tomcat is random.

Comment: Apache Tomcat is not a DBMS. It is a servlet container and as such it simply does not store a database. This implies that you must be using a third party module that does. A stack trace would have easily revealed which module you are using and where stuff goes wrong. But luckily you mentioned the `url = "jdbc:h2:sudoDb;...."` which suggests you are using a H2 JDBC driver of unknown version that is able to store a database. This might help: https://www.h2database.com/html/faq.html#database_files

Comment: Thank you for the answer, tried it and works fine

Answer (score 0):

As my webApp is based on grails and h2 defining the database location in config.DataSource worked for me. I simply defined:

```
url = "jdbc:h2:file:/vol/h2/sudoDb....
```

and the database was stored by tomcat in /vol/h2 of my target linux. This is indeed not an operating system independent solution as it only works for tomcats running on linux. For windows still a recompile with another url='...' is needed.